# EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'C:\Users\**\node_modules\.node-sass.DELETE\vendor\win32-x64-57\binding.node'

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

When I run "npm install", I get an error.

> OS: Windows 10 npm: 6.2.0 node: v10.9.0

I already tried to `"npm install"` after `"npm cache verify"` but I couldn't solved it.

```
npm cache verify 
npm instal
```

> npm ERR! path
>   C:\Users\ipiag\products\tor\src\node_modules.node-sass.DELETE\vendor\win32-x64-57\binding.node
>   npm ERR! code EPERM
>   npm ERR! errno -4048
>   npm ERR! syscall unlink
>   npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink
>   'C:\Users\ipiag\products\tor\src\node_modules.node-sass.DELETE\vendor\win32-x64-57\binding.node'
>   npm ERR!  { [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink
>   'C:\Users\ipiag\products\tor\src\node_modules.node-sass.DELETE\vendor\win32-x64-57\binding.node']
>   npm ERR!   cause:
>   npm ERR!    { Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink
>   'C:\Users\ipiag\products\tor\src\node_modules.node-sass.DELETE\vendor\win32-x64-57\binding.node'
>   npm ERR!      errno: -4048,
>   npm ERR!      code: 'EPERM',
>   npm ERR!      syscall: 'unlink',
>   npm ERR!      path:
>   npm ERR!
>   'C:\Users\ipiag\products\tor\src\node_modules\.node-sass.DELETE\vendor\win32-x64-57\binding.node'
>   },                                                     npm ERR!
>   stack:
>   npm ERR!    'Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink
>   \'C:\Users\ipiag\products\tor\src\node_modules\.node-sass.DELETE\vendor\win32-x64-57\binding.node\'',
>   npm ERR!   errno: -4048,
>   npm ERR!   code: 'EPERM',
>   npm ERR!   syscall: 'unlink',
>   npm ERR!   path:
>   npm ERR!
>   'C:\Users\ipiag\products\tor\src\node_modules\.node-sass.DELETE\vendor\win32-x64-57\binding.node',
>   npm ERR!   parent: 'tor' }
>   npm ERR!
>   npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
>   npm ERR! It's possible that the file was already in use (by a text
>   editor or antivirus),
>   npm ERR! or that you lack permissions to access it.
>   npm ERR!
>   npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please
>   double-check the
>   npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or
>   try running
>   npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator (though this is not
>   recommended).
>
> ```
>                                                                                                                                                                               npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
> ```
>
> npm ERR!
>   C:\Users\ipiag\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2019-06-12T02_32_33_624Z-debug.log

Comment: Try removing the `node_modules` folder. Then `npm install` instead of `npm instal`.

Answer (score 36):

In my case, i killed all nodejs running processes and it worked.

Comment: Yep, same goes for if you are running React. I stopped it and it installed fine.

Comment: This worked for me. There were "node" processes in windows and I manually end them and it worked.

Answer (score 9):

This usually happens when you are running `node` and then try to do an `npm install` in your project.

Check if you are running gulp like `gulp build:server` or any npm scripts (like `npm run xxxx`) for your project. Then stop those and you will be able to successfully complete `npm install` command.

Comment: Killed all node tasks from Task Manager(Windows 10) and then again executed the commands. It worked!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, I manually removed `.node-sass.DELETE` from `node_modules`

Then run:

```
npm cache verify

npm install
```

Answer (score 1):

On Windows, closing Node wasn't enough.

I had to open a shell in **Admin Mode** and stop all Node and Electron processes.

Here are the four apps I know can lock some files in node_modules directories

```
stop-process -Name node
stop-process -Name electron
stop-process -Name chromedriver
stop-process -Name chrome          # ChromeDriver can spawn some apps during tests in hidden mode
```