# npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system. Error while creating a reac app

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm

I have installed the 14.17.3 LTS version of node ( npm version 6.14.13 ).

After that I have successfully installed create-react-app globally using command "npm install -g create-react-app" (version 4.0.3).

When i am creating a react app in one of my folder in E drive using command "create-react-app my-app" , it is giving me error which i have listed below with complete log.

"
Creating a new React app in E:\react-app\todo-app.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...

> core-js@2.6.12 postinstall E:\react-app\todo-app\node_modules\babel-runtime\node_modules\core-js
> node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"

> core-js@3.15.2 postinstall E:\react-app\todo-app\node_modules\core-js
> node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"

> core-js-pure@3.15.2 postinstall E:\react-app\todo-app\node_modules\core-js-pure
> node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"

> ejs@2.7.4 postinstall E:\react-app\todo-app\node_modules\ejs
> node ./postinstall.js

- react-dom@17.0.2
- cra-template@1.1.2
- react@17.0.2
- react-scripts@4.0.3
  added 1897 packages from 703 contributors and audited 1900 packages in 769.172s

145 packages are looking for funding
run `npm fund` for details

found 5 vulnerabilities (3 moderate, 2 high)
run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details

Initialized a git repository.

Installing template dependencies using npm...

npm WARN @babel/plugin-bugfix-v8-spread-parameters-in-optional-chaining@7.14.5 requires a peer of @babel/core@^7.13.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

npm WARN tsutils@3.21.0 requires a peer of typescript@>=2.8.0 || >= 3.2.0-dev || >= 3.3.0-dev || >= 3.4.0-dev || >= 3.5.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-beta || >= 3.7.0-dev || >= 3.7.0-beta but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

npm ERR! code EPERM

npm ERR! syscall unlink

npm ERR! path E:\react-app\todo-app\node_modules.staging

npm ERR! errno -4048

npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'E:\react-app\todo-app\node_modules.staging'

npm ERR!  [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'E:\react-app\todo-app\node_modules.staging'] {

npm ERR!   errno: -4048,

npm ERR!   code: 'EPERM',

npm ERR!   syscall: 'unlink',

npm ERR!   path: 'E:\react-app\todo-app\node_modules\.staging'

npm ERR! }

npm ERR!

npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.

npm ERR! It's possible that the file was already in use (by a text editor or antivirus),

npm ERR! or that you lack permissions to access it.

npm ERR!

npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the

npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running

npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:

npm ERR!     C:\Users\pc\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2021-07-07T05_35_37_097Z-debug.log

`npm install --save @testing-library/jest-dom@^5.11.4 @testing-library/react@^11.1.0 @testing-library/user-event@^12.1.10 web-vitals@^1.0.1` failed
"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'C:\Users\‌\*\*\node\_modules\.node-sass.DELETE\vendor\win32-x64-57\binding.node'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56554646/eperm-operation-not-permitted-unlink-c-users-node-modules-node-sass-dele)

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem also, this is how I fixed it,

open your terminal and go into your app directory `for your case is my-app`

then run `npm i @babel/core@^7.13.0`

and then run `npm i typescript@>=2.8.0`

**NOTE: This will remove those warnings only but am not sure if other errors will gone also**

I hope this may help you.